# Change assigned style

Tags: view-styles, metadata-navigation

I'd like change assigned style `display` of `ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_ctl01_WebTreeViewn1Nodes` from `"none"` to `"block"`

and style `height` of `ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_ctl01_TreeViewRememberScroll`.

Is it possible? It is in Metadata navigation on the left site of a window.

I tried this:

[image]

Comment: along with height have you tried `display:block` ?

Comment: firstly no, till now, it does not work

Answer (score 2):

Should you try this :

```
<style>

#ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_ctl01_TreeViewRememberScroll
{
height : 150px ! important;
}

#ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_ctl01_WebTreeViewn1Nodes 
{
display : block ! important;
}

</style>
```

Comment: thanks, changing height works fine, but set display to block no, because ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_ctl01_WebTreeViewn1Nodes does not exist untill click on the top o tree to unwrat it